# GitLab installation was incomplete on Xcode Cloud Setup

Tags: xcode, react-native, xcode-cloud

I am unable to connect my gitlab account with xcloud. It was previously connected but I had deleted the Xcode Cloud data after we have changed our gitlab remote origin url. Since then whenever I am trying to connect, I am getting this error "Gitlab installation was incomplete". I have tried connecting the account with both maintainer & admin account but still getting the same error.

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have same problem

Comment: Not Yet, have also posted it on apple forum but no response received from there as well. https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/728477